# Is it possible to use camera on < 21 and camera2 on 21+?

Tags: android, api, android-camera, android-appcompat, camera2

I would like to use `camera2`, because it have features that we want. But it's important to stay compatible with <21 API versions. So, I have `CameraActivity` and `CameraController` classes that using `Camera`. Is it possible to use `android.hardware.Camera` on old devices and `android.hardware.camera2` on new?

Comment: depends on your needs (prolly you wana show some preview) so make a common interface inside PreviewFragmentImplBase then  `if(API < 21) { usePreviewFragmentImplBase } else {usePreviewFragmenImpl22 }` ...

Comment: android studio will not require to change version to 21 if I'll use this class?

Comment: [which one?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) or buildSDK? in gradle ...  you can always build with the newest SDK version but you have to do checks if you are using newest API on old platform ... thats how the compat library is builded

Comment: Thanks, you can add it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use numerous SDK versions as you like.

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

edit: Credit to selvin also. While I was searching for this, he beat me to it!